# Java classloader issue in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, classloader

I am seeing a class-loader issue while deploying Spring Boot application.

All the library jars are inside the single Spring Boot jar. I have verified that using `jar -tf` command.

Now, I ran the application using `java -verbose -jar`, but it's facing a weird classloader issue.

In the logs, I am able to see the class already loaded:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.asd.myconnector.MyPPManager
        at com.asd.db.datamanager.MySystemDataManager.getProjectSystemProperties(SystemDM.java:195) ~[core-0.0.1.jar!/:na]
```

and just few lines above, I am able to see this class already loaded:

```
[Loaded com.asd.myconnector.MyPPManager from jar:file:/home/abhay/myconnections-0.1.15.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/core-0.0.1.jar!/]
```

Can anyone help any pointers where I can look into?

Thanks and Regards,

Abhay Dandekar